# How spinlocked threads avoid overhead of context switching?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

In wikipedia, the aritcle about spinlocks.

> Because they avoid overhead from operating system process rescheduling or context switching, spinlocks are efficient if threads are likely to be blocked for only short periods.

I actually can't grasp this sentence.
I think that even if a thread has a spinlock, it's going to be rescheduled, am I wrong ?

The context switching over-head - which is saving the registers,pc  & scheduling queue - is constant for all switches, isn't it?

Comment: The thread that is spinning, i.e. busy wait, assumes that the lock-to-be-gotten will free up shortly, but stays in its timeslice.  So, instead of just jumping immediately into a wait state by waiting on the lock, thus causing a context switch (because thread gives up the rest of its timeslice), the thread will try to avoid the context switch by the busy wait for a limited time.

Comment: There is a limited set of conditions under which a spinlock outperforms a kernel lock.  The likelihood of a short interval of contention is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I actually can't grasp this sentence. I think that even if a thread
>   has a spinlock, it's going to be rescheduled, am I wrong ?

Eventually it would be... when its timeslice expired.

What a spinlock avoids is the chance of having the thread get context-switched out *immediately* whenever it tries to acquire and the lock is already locked by another thread.

(In the traditional mutex case, when the mutex is already locked, the thread would immediately be put to sleep aka context-switched out, and it would not be reawoken until after the other thread had unlocked the mutex.  In spinlock case, OTOH, the thread would just keep checking the spinlock's state in a tight loop, until the spinlock was no longer locked, and then the thread would lock the spinlock for itself.  Note that at no point during that process would the thread ask the kernel to put the thread to sleep, although if it spun for a long time its possible the kernel would do anyway... but a program using spinlocks will hopefully never lock them for a long time anyway, since spinning is really inefficient)

> The context switching over-head - which is saving the registers,pc &
>   scheduling queue - is constant for all switches, isn't it?

Yes, I believe it is.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the second question ?

Comment: Eventually it would be... when its timeslice expired... or it was removed from the running set by another of the many classes of interrupt.  The timer interrupt is only one possible cause of a thread losing execution, and giving it undue attention, and/or failing to mention the other possibilities, just adds FUD :(

Comment: FUD?  Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt

Answer (score 2):

Generally an OS is only going to use spinlocks in interrupt service routines. These are designed to be of short duration.

> I actually can't grasp this sentence. I think that even if a thread has a spinlock, it's going to be rescheduled, am I wrong ?

Not while it is handling an interrupt (simplifying here that only there is only one IPL). That interrupt might be the timer interrupt where the a context switch may take place. However, in that situation, the spinlock wait would be for the resources necessary to process a context switch.